# StackService: Preempt user logins and assign roles and permissions on login

Tags: authentication, servicestack, azure-active-directory, roles

I'm looking for a way to assign Roles and Permissions to a user whose email I know but has not yet logged into my service. Auth is done using external auth providers (aad).

I played around with clearing the UserAuth and UserAuthDetails tables and then creating a bare minimum UserAuth entry that anticipates my login (id, email, username and dates) but upon signing in another UserAuth entry was created to go along with the new UserAuthDetails row.

Right now I'm (getting away with) hardcoding roles (and other metadata) and applying them during OnAuthenticated. At some point I might have to reluctantly move this to a table in the database so I can add pre-emptive access assignment during runtime.

Ideally I should be able to pre-create UserAuth rows with the appropriates Roles and Permissions that anticipate that users login using a provider that matches the email. Can I add this functionality through ServiceStack's extension mechanisms without actually modifying the underlying AuthenticateService?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you know exactly what UserAuth to create, I'd still modify them in `OnAuthenticated()` but you can source them from a custom `CreateRole` table which lists the `Role` that should be created against a users `Email` that way you can assign it to them when they authenticate, e.g:

```
public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, 
    IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
{
    using (var db = authService.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
    {
        var q = db.From<CreateRole>().Where(x => x.Email == session.Email);
        var userRoles = db.Column<string>(q.Select(x => x.Role));

        var authRepo = authService.TryResolve<IAuthRepository>();
        var userAuth = authRepo.GetUserAuth(session, tokens);
        authRepo.AssignRoles(userAuth, roles: userRoles);
    }
}
```